# Edit groups in user edit form in Django

Tags: python, django

I do not use admin apps in *Django*, and I want to edit the user with form, but when I edit the groups to the users, Django doesn't save my choice and user has no groups.

**`views.py`**:

```
def useredit(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditUserForm(request.POST, instance=user)

        if form.is_valid():
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Utilisateur édité avec succés !')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user')
    else:
        form = EditUserForm(instance=user)

    return render(request, 'compta/users/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

**`forms.py`**:

```
class EditUserForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit)
        self._save_m2m()

        return user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save form instead of user instance
replace

```
    if form.is_valid():
        user.save()
        #^^^^
```

with

```
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        #^^^^
```

Comment: Hmm, i've now this error: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given) what going wrong ?

Comment: Looks like you're using Python 2.x, in which case your call to `super()` needs arguments: `super(EditUserForm, self).save(commit)` would be correct.

Comment: Yeah Thx i use Python 2, its better to use 3 ?